# How to do a efficient contained search among two columns?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a DriverEntity which is having a private property i.e., DriverInfoEntity which is having driver's first name and last name.

Sample code :

```
public class DriverEntity{
    
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "driver-info")
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "driver", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private DriverInfoEntity driverInfo;
.
.
.
//few other private attributes

}

public class DriverInfoEntity  {

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "MIDDLE_NAME")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
.
.
//few other private attributes

 }
```

And I am doing a contained search on the firstName and lastName columns using specification Builder. Idea is to search based on the provided **driverName** which may be **only firstName** or **(firstName +' '+ lastName)** or **only lastName**.

Logic written is:

```
public Specification buildSpecification(Specification specification) {
if (driverSearchRequestFilterDTO.getDriverName() != null) {
            List<Object> referenceList = new ArrayList<>();
            referenceList.add(DriverEntity_.driverInfo);
            specification = specification.and(specificationBuilder
                    .getSpecificationForConcatField(referenceList, DriverInfoEntity_.firstName,
                            DriverInfoEntity_.lastName, driverSearchRequestFilterDTO.getDriverName()));
        }
        return specification;
}
```

[image]

```
public static Predicate buildConcatPredicateWithJoin(Root root, Join joinCondition, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder,
        SingularAttribute firstColumn, SingularAttribute secondColumn, String inputQuery) {

    Predicate firstColumnLike;
    Predicate secondColumnLike;
    Predicate firstSecondColumnLike;
    Predicate secondFirstColumnLike;

    if (Objects.nonNull(root)) {
        firstColumnLike = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get(firstColumn)), inputQuery.replaceAll("\\*", "%"));
        secondColumnLike = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get(secondColumn)), inputQuery.replaceAll("\\*", "%"));

        //combination of firstColumn + " " + second column
        Expression<String> exp1 = criteriaBuilder.concat(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get(firstColumn)), " ");
        exp1 = criteriaBuilder.concat(exp1, criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get(secondColumn)));
        firstSecondColumnLike = criteriaBuilder.like(exp1, inputQuery.replaceAll("\\*", "%"));

        //combination of secondColumn + " " + firstColumn
        Expression<String> exp2 = criteriaBuilder.concat(criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get(secondColumn)), " ");
        exp2 = criteriaBuilder.concat(exp2, criteriaBuilder.lower(root.get(firstColumn)));
        secondFirstColumnLike = criteriaBuilder.like(exp2, inputQuery.replaceAll("\\*", "%"));
    } else {
        firstColumnLike = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(joinCondition.get(firstColumn)), inputQuery.replaceAll("\\*", "%"));
        secondColumnLike = criteriaBuilder.like(criteriaBuilder.lower(joinCondition.get(secondColumn)), inputQuery.replaceAll("\\*", "%"));
        // to search by first name
        Expression<String> exp1 = criteriaBuilder.concat(criteriaBuilder.lower(joinCondition.get(firstColumn)), " ");
        exp1 = criteriaBuilder.concat(exp1, criteriaBuilder.lower(joinCondition.get(secondColumn)));

        firstSecondColumnLike = criteriaBuilder.like(exp1, inputQuery.replaceAll("\\*", "%"));

        //to search by last name
        Expression<String> exp2 = criteriaBuilder.concat(criteriaBuilder.lower(joinCondition.get(secondColumn)), " ");
        exp2 = criteriaBuilder.concat(exp2, criteriaBuilder.lower(joinCondition.get(firstColumn)));

        secondFirstColumnLike = criteriaBuilder.like(exp2, inputQuery.replaceAll("\\*", "%"));
    }
    return criteriaBuilder.or(firstColumnLike, secondColumnLike, firstSecondColumnLike, secondFirstColumnLike);
}
```

And the main SQL query which is getting created :
[image]

The whole code is working fine but having **mojor impact on performance** when we are having lots of data. As the processing at the **backend taking lot of time** for huge data set.
I would need some enlightenment to make this process quick enough so that it can filter out the huge set of drivers efficiently ?

**Info regarding front-end** : At the UI we have auto-complete feature which shows only 20 records at a time if if the search is successful whereas the record per page is being implemented at the backend. And that's why I am using **Limit** in the SQL query.

As you can see it shows the results here in the drop down.

[image]

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL so we can discuss it from that point of view.

Comment: Hi Rick, yes I have pasted the screenshot of the generated SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

If the two name columns have a collation that is "case_insensive" you don't need the `LOWER()` calls.  Then the the `WHERE` clause might be as simple as

```
WHERE first_name = ? OR last_name = ?
```

If you are planning to allow wild cards, then

```
WHERE first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ?
```

What the heck is the `CONCAT()` for?

However, my suggestion is mostly a simplification, it still requires checking every row.  That is because of the `OR`.

About the only way to get rid of the `OR` is to use a `UNION`, but that gets messy:

```
( SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    JOIN ... ON ...
    WHERE first_name LIKE ? 
    LIMIT ?)
UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    JOIN ... ON ...
    WHERE last_name LIKE ?
    LIMIT ? )
LIMIT ?
```

plus

```
INDEX(first_name),
INDEX(last_name)
```

Then there are outer issues...

- A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` does not make much sense.
- If you will also have `OFFSET`, it gets messier
- If the user provides a *leading* wild card on the `LIKE` string, then it will still have to do a table scan; in fact two scans.

A `FULLTEXT` index could be used, but it has limitations, and you would need to combine the two columns into a single column.  That way one name would match either first or last *very* efficiently.  But the user would have to enter the full first and/or last name, not just an initial.

**Auto-complete**

Since the purpose is for an auto-complete UI, I will assume there is no leading wildcard on the `LIKE`.  But, if you still need to check the entry of either first or last name, then the UNION is necessary.

Have the Javascript avoid asking for names until the user has entered at least two letters.  This will limit the returned list to under 1% of the total (usually).  I suspect that currently you are asking for a list after the first letter and it is looking at 10% of the names.

Without the indexes and union, up to 100% of the table is read each time.  My suggestions above limit it to "up to 1%", thereby making things 100x faster.  (Well, for various reasons, do not count on a full 100x.)

You must decide what to do about ordering of the subqueries of the Union and of the union as a whole.  Otherwise, there will be some surprising lists coming back.  The user experience will be sub-par.

Comment: Let us suppose we have Driver named "Adam Smith" then user can enter names from the text field like :  Adam, Smith, ada, adam, smith, adam smit or Adam Smith. So driverName variable can contain all such types of text to do a search and at UI we have auto complete which shows the driver's having the name given in text field.

Comment: So to encounter the scenarios where user may enter texts with both first and last name by just a comma separation in the driverName variable, I have used concat().

Comment: Limit is used because we have pagination implementation at the backend where we are giving only 20 records per page.

Comment: @anaz_Zean07 - If your question assumes "auto complete", then say so in the Question.  There are significant short cuts that we can apply.  Better yet, start a new Question.  Then we can discuss how to store and access the data for such, and also why pagination might not be relevant.

Comment: Hi Rick, I have updated my question with all the information that is required and how my current application is behaving. Could you please suggest me how to achieve the same task efficiently now?